# Request failed with status code 401 at createError "Unauthenticated"

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm using laravel with reactjs I'm getting this problem when I'm doing logout

[image: 1]

```js
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
// axios.defaults.headers.common = {'Authorization': 'bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('auth_token')}
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config){
    const token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    // config.headers["Authorization"] = "bearer " + token;
    config.headers.Authorization = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
    return config;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So what does that logout api do this is clearly a permission error coming from laravel. Show the logout method from the backend. Also check your network you can see the full message there.